# Python sys.stdout.write() strange behavior in Mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am trying to make a progress bar for a process, but to keep things short consider the following snippet:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
  time.sleep(0.5)
  sys.stdout.write('*')
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

What I am expecting it to do is to print a star every half a second on the same line (which is exactly what it does when I run the code with an IDE like Sublime Text for example). However, when I run this in the Mac OS Terminal it just waits for 5 seconds then prints the whole string `**********` at once.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to get the desired behavior?

Comment: My guess is line buffering.  Try `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `sys.stdout.write('*') call.`  (Alternatively, call python with the `-u` command line option: `python -u yourprogram.py`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does that because output is buffered. Try this instead:

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.write('*')
    sys.stdout.flush()    # <-- this is the key
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

By flushing output each time you do a write, `sys.stdout` won't wait for the next newline; instead it will write whatever characters are in its buffers immediately.

Answer (score 3):

The output is being buffered, so you will need to call `sys.stdout.flush()` after each write operation to flush the buffer.

Or, even better, just use [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and have Python do it for you.  In versions 3.3+, the code would be:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print('*', end='', flush=True)
print()
```

If you are using an older version, you would omit the `flush=True`:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print('*', end='')
print()
```

And if you happen to be using Python 2.x, you will also need to write:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of your code to use the Python 3.x `print`.  For more information, see [`__future__` — Future statement definitions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) in the documentation.

Comment: black magic... yes I am using python 2.7 and your solution works great, however it adds a whitespace between stars and I can't tell where it comes from...I guess it is what print does by default, adding newlines and whitespaces...or?

Comment: on python2.7 I get `TypeError: 'flush' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: @skamsie and all others who upvoted his/her comment: the `flush` argument works only in Python 3.3 and above. See original post or the Python 3 docs.